# A doubt concerning the central limit theorem and how it is presented in explanatory videos

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

As a mathematician currently pursuing a master's degree in machine learning, I aim to develop an intuitive understanding of statistics, particularly concerning the Central Limit Theorem (CLT). While I comprehend that the CLT implies the convergence of cumulative distribution functions, a specific aspect related to Bernoulli variables puzzles me.

In various educational videos on the Central Limit Theorem, there seems to be a strong implication that the frequency histogram of the probability density function for the variable $T_{n} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}}{\sqrt{n}\,\sigma} - \sqrt{n}\,\mu$ converges uniformly on compact sets to the graph of the Gaussian distribution. I have reconstructed a possible definition for this sequences of histograms as a piecewise constant functions:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} P(\{ T_{N} = s^{N}_{i} \}) \cdot \mathbb{1}_{[x^{N}_{i},x^{N}_{i+1})}
$$

where each interval $[x^{N}_{i},x^{N}_{i+1})$ contains exactly one of the values $s_{i}^{N}$ assumed by $T_{N}$, and $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

However, despite watching numerous explanatory videos, there seems to be a gap in my understanding. I suspect that a crucial detail may be eluding me. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could shed light on this or provide a reference for further exploration.

Comment: The convergence is uniform, namely $$\sup_t |F_n(t)-F(t)|\to 0$$ This is not a consequence, per se, of the central limit theorem, but of the more general well known fact that if $F$ is continuous, then one always has uniform convergence

Comment: The Andrew comment is likely intended to be for CDFs: If $F_n(t)$ is a nondecreasing function of $t$ for each fixed $n \in \{1,2,3,...\}$, and if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}F_n(t)=F(t)$ for all $t$ and for some continuous function $F(t)$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$, then the convergence is uniform over compact sets. There are counter-examples when $F_n(t)$ is not necessarily nondecreasing in $t$ (although such counter-examples do not exist if $F_n(t)$ is a CDF).

Comment: In educational videos they demo strate when $X_n$ is integer-valued, and in this case, using some variation of $$P(X = j) = P(j - 1/2 < X < j + 1/2)$$ and the fundamental theorem of calculus to get a result about the PMFs converging to the standard normal density.

Comment: By the way I have now searched 2 "educational videos" on the CLT and they actually claim "after sampling it is very easy to see this is a normal distribution" (and they draw a bell curve over fake data as a "proof"). In other words those are not really very eductional. They also seem to be misleading as (at least the ones I watched) didn't really tell you how they are computing a sample of the means and defining the histogram (no $\sqrt{n}$ scaling was mentioned). This is not really a way to understand the CLT. The real intuition  is to go through the transfer function.

Comment: You will get more actual intuition (in comparison to the videos) by assuming $\{X_i\}$ are iid with mean $m$ and variance $\sigma^2>0$ and computing the mean and variance of $G_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-m)$. This will not give you distribution info, but you will see how the mean and variance are preserved for all $n$. Use the fact that the variance of a sum of independent variables is the sum of variances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Direct feedback:** In your question you give the following expression:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} P(\{ T_{N} = s^{N}_{i} \}) \cdot \mathbb{1}_{[x^{N}_{i},x^{N}_{i+1})}
$$
This expression does not make sense here:

- What is the definition of $s_i^N$? Is it random? Why are there only $N$ possible values of $s_i^N$?
- What is the definition of your indicator function $1_{[x_i^N, x_{i+1}^N)}$? Is this a random variable? A function of some variable $x$?
- What type of object is that expression? Is it a number? A random variable?

---

**CLT Statement:** If $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) with finite mean $\mu$ and finite and nonzero variance $\sigma^2$ then
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[T_n\leq x] = P[G\leq x] \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
where $G \sim N(0,1)$ and $T_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)$ for $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.

---

**On histogram visualizations of the CLT:** Sometimes $n=20$ is large enough for $T_{20}$ to have a distribution that is close to (but not the same as) a Gaussian $N(0,1)$ distribution.

*How can we visualize this?*

Well, we can first choose some distribution for the $X_i$ variables, say, $X_i \sim Unif(0,1)$ (so $\mu=1/2$, $\sigma^2=1/12$).  We can make two intervals $I_1=[0.1, 0.2)$ and $I_2=[0.2, 0.3)$ and then, somehow, attempt to show
\begin{align*}
P[T_{20}\in I_1] &\approx P[G \in I_1] = \int_{0.1}^{0.2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2}dt\\
P[T_{20} \in I_2] &\approx P[G \in I_2]= \int_{0.2}^{0.3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2}dt\\
\end{align*}
We can of course consider any finite collection of intervals that we want, but for simplicity lets just consider intervals $I_1$ and $I_2$.

The challenge is that the distribution of $T_{20}$ is **very complicated** (it is not Gaussian). To compute the PDF of $T_{20}$, we would need to convolve scaled versions of the uniform PDF with itself 20 times. *Therefore, it is not easy to compute exact values of $P[T_{20} \in I_1]$ and $P[T_{20} \in I_2]$.* However, it is easy to generate i.i.d. random variables $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$, all having the same distribution as $T_{20}$. Then we can take a histogram of how many times the $Y_i$ samples fall into the given intervals and use the **law of large numbers** (LLN) to claim that this converges (with probability 1) to the exact probability for $P[T_{20} \in I_1]$ and $P[T_{20}\in I_2]$.

To do this lets arrange i.i.d. samples of the $U(0,1)$ distribution into a doubly-indexed collection of random variables: $X_{i,j}$ for $i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ and $j \in \{1, ..., 20\}$. Define
$$ Y_i =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sigma^2}}\sum_{j=1}^{20}(X_{i,j}-\mu)  \quad \forall i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$
Since for different indices $i$ we are using different samples $X_{i,j}$, we know $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. with distribution the same as $T_{20}$. Thus, the random variables
$\{W_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ defined below are also i.i.d., as are $\{Z_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$:
$$ W_i = 1_{\{Y_i \in I_1\}} \quad \forall i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$
$$ Z_i = 1_{\{Y_i \in I_2\}} \quad \forall i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$
By the LLN we know (with prob 1):
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nW_i = E[W_1] = P[Y_1 \in I_1] = P[T_{20}\in I_1]$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i = E[Z_1] = P[Y_1 \in I_2] = P[T_{20}\in I_2]$$

Observe that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n W_i$ and $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i$ are just histogram values for the fraction of time being in the intervals $I_1$ and $I_2$. If $n$ is large then (with high probability) these are close to the exact values of $P[T_{20}\in I_1]$ and $P[T_{20} \in I_2]$.

Now, taking $n\rightarrow\infty$ does not give any convergence to a Gaussian. No, it only (by the law of large numbers) gives convergence with probability 1 to the exact values $P[T_{20}\in I_1]$ and $P[T_{20} \in I_2]$.  Since 20 is "large" we may expect these exact values to be close to $P[G \in I_1]$ and $P[G \in I_2]$. If we like, we can directly compare the results by using experimental data.

If you want to visualize a closer convergence to a Gaussian, you can take batches of size 30 (rather than batches of size 20). Then we can approximate $P[T_{30} \in I_1]$ and $P[T_{30} \in I_2]$, which will be closer approximations to $P[G \in I_1]$ and $P[G \in I_2]$.

Comment: Note: I am giving two answers. My first answer was based on reading the first half of the OP question, which deals with a more advanced concept of uniform convergence over compact sets. This answer is based on observing that the OP seems to be really asking a more basic question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a statement and proof of the related result in comments.

**Claim:** Suppose that

- We have (possibly discontinuous) functions $\{F_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of the form $F_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.
- For each $n\in\{1,2,3,...\}$, $F_n(x)$ is nondecreasing in $x$ (so $x<y\implies F_n(x)\leq F_n(y)$).
- We have a continuous function $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.
- $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} F_n(x) = F(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then for each compact interval $[a,b] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and each $\epsilon>0$, there is a positive integer $m$ such that
$$ \sup_{x \in [a,b]}|F_n(x)-F(x)|\leq \epsilon \quad \forall n \geq m$$
This is called "uniform convergence over compact sets."

**Note:** We can apply this to your CLT question by defining $F_n$ as the CDF function of $T_n$ and $F$ as the CDF of a $N(0,1)$ Gaussian. Then $F_n(x)$ is nondecreasing in $x$ for each fixed $n$. Also, $F$ is continuous. So if we believe the standard CLT result that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} F_n(x)=F(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the above claim also gives us uniform convergence over compact sets.

**Proof of claim:** Fix interval $[a,b]$ (assume $a<b$). Fix $\epsilon>0$. Since $F$ is continuous it is uniformly continuous over the compact interval $[a,b]$. So there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $x,y \in [a,b]$ then
$$(|x-y|\leq \delta) \implies |F(x)-F(y)|\leq \epsilon/2$$
Chop $[a,b]$ into $k$ equally spaced subintervals, each of size no more than $\delta$. Let $\{x_i\}_{i=0}^k$ be the grid points (so $x_0=a$, $x_k=b$). Choose $m$ such that $n\geq m$ implies $|F_n(x_i)-F(x_i)|\leq \epsilon/2$ for all $i \in \{0, ..., k\}$.

Now fix $y \in [a,b]$ and $n\geq m$. Note that $x_i\leq y\leq x_{i+1}$ for some $i \in\{0,1,...,k\}$. Since $F_n(x)$ is nondecreasing in $x$, by considering the two cases either $F_n(y)\leq F(y)$ or $F_n(y)>F(y)$, we get:
$$|F_n(y)-F(y)|\leq \max\{|F_n(x_i)-F(y)|, |F_n(x_{i+1})-F(y)|\} \quad (*)$$
On the other hand by the triangle inequality we get
$$ |F_n(x_i)-F(y)|\leq |F_n(x_i)-F(x_i)|+|F(x_i)-F(y)|\leq \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon$$
since $n\geq m$ and $|x_i-y|\leq \delta$. Similarly
$$ |F_n(x_{i+1})-F(y)|\leq \epsilon$$
It follows from (*) that
$$|F_n(y)-F(y)|\leq \epsilon$$
This holds for all $y \in [a,b]$. $\Box$

Comment: In the special case when $F$ is a CDF function we can extend to uniform convergence over all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ because we can fix $\epsilon>0$ and then choose $[a,b]$ such that $F(a)\leq \epsilon/2$ and $F(b)\geq 1-\epsilon/2$.

Comment: @Micheal I'm sorry you went through writing all these results that I already know. My curiosity was more toward a possible convergence, at least punctual convergence, of the piecewise constant functions that I tried to define. Are you saying that the images on the videos were all misleading pictures and that there are no results similar to the one I tried to state?

Comment: @MatteoAldovardi : See my additional answer.